# Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Double' is not valid when returns empty data

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I have a page which has complex queries. Queries working properly but whenever there is null or empty string it throws this errors.

Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Double' is not valid.

This my code

```
If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
            Dim dt As DataTable = Me.GetData("SELECT (`behaviour`+`treatment`+`charges`+`information`+`hygine`+`admission`)/6 AverageRating, COUNT(ID) RatingCount from ratings WHERE hospitalID Like '%" + var2 + "%';")
            avg.Text = FormatNumber(CDbl(dt.Rows(0)("AverageRating")), 1)
            totalVotes.Text = String.Format(dt.Rows(0)("RatingCount"))
        End If
```

avg.text gets values from db on page load

Comment: Either check for null befor casting, or fix your SQL statement to replace NULL with 0. And replace string concatenation with parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to,

```
SELECT (isnull(`behaviour`,0)+isnull(`treatment`,0)+isnull(`charges`,0)+isnull(`information`,0)+isnull(`hygine`,0)+isnull(`admission`,0))/6 AverageRating, COUNT(ID) RatingCount from ratings
```

Answer (score 0):

Use isnull function in your SQL.

Example : Select Name ,isnull(rating,0)

If rating=null  the sql will return 0

Answer (score 0):

`Double.TryParse(text, value)` is best at testing

```
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
    Dim testDouble as Double
    Dim dt As DataTable = Me.GetData("SELECT (`behaviour`+`treatment`+`charges`+`information`+`hygine`+`admission`)/6 AverageRating, COUNT(ID) RatingCount from ratings WHERE hospitalID Like '%" + var2 + "%';")

    If Double.TryParse((dt.Rows(0)("AverageRating")), testDouble) Then
        ' text is convertible to Double, and testDouble contains the Double value now'
        avg.Text = FormatNumber(testDouble, 1)
    Else
        ' Cannot convert text to Double'
    End If
        totalVotes.Text = String.Format(dt.Rows(0)("RatingCount"))
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Use extension method [DataRowExtensions.Field Method (DataRow, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx)

From documentation:

> If the value of the specified DataColumn is null and T is a reference
>   type or nullable type, the return type will be null.

```vb
If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
    Dim dt As DataTable = Me.GetData("SELECT ....")
    Dim avgValue As Double? = dt.Rows(0).Field(Of Double?)("AverageRating")
    If avgValue.HasValue = True Then
        avg.Text = avgValue.Value.ToString()
    Else
        avg.Text = "no value"
    End If

End If
```